# Using R: How to subselect cases by quarterly dates and identify unique cases by a separate variable within each quarter?

Tags: r, date, unique

[EDITED 4/4/2020] This is my first post on stackoverflow and I'm a new R user. Please forgive me for any errors.
I'm using R 3.6.2 with Rstudio. 
In this dataset I am hoping to find a way to keep unique ID cases within each quarter of the year. Many people take multiple medications in the same quarter, I want to know who was administered any medication within each quarter. So unique ID's within each quarter of the year.

```
> Df<-data.frame(ID= c("123",   "456",  "123", "789",   "123",  "456",  "789",  "123",  "789"),
+                Drug= c("A",   "B",    "C",    "A",    "A",    "A",    "B",    "B",    "A"),
+                Administered= c("2017 Q1", "2018 Q1",  "2017 Q3",  "2017 Q1",  "2017 Q1",  "2018 Q3",  "2018 Q1",  "2017 Q1",  "2018 Q1"))
> 
> dput(Df)  ##Generating dput format
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L), .Label = c("123", "456", "789"), class = "factor"), Drug = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    Administered = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L), .Label = c("2017 Q1", "2017 Q3", "2018 Q1", "2018 Q3"
    ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
> 
> str(Df)  ##demonstrating structure of data
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ ID          : Factor w/ 3 levels "123","456","789": 1 2 1 3 1 2 3 1 3
 $ Drug        : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3 1 1 1 2 2 1
 $ Administered: Factor w/ 4 levels "2017 Q1","2017 Q3",..: 1 3 2 1 1 4 3 1 3
> 
> print(Df)  ##Before removing duplicates
   ID Drug Administered
1 123    A      2017 Q1
2 456    B      2018 Q1
3 123    C      2017 Q3
4 789    A      2017 Q1
5 123    A      2017 Q1
6 456    A      2018 Q3
7 789    B      2018 Q1
8 123    B      2017 Q1
9 789    A      2018 Q1
> 
> library(tidyverse) ##Loading tidyverse for distinct function to remove duplicates
> 
> Df %>% distinct(ID, .keep_all=TRUE) ##Removed duplicate enteries but wanted to remove duplicates IDs within each Year Quarter
   ID Drug Administered
1 123    A      2017 Q1
2 456    B      2018 Q1
3 789    A      2017 Q1
> 
> ##Generating the end result dataset desired where only duplicate ID's within each quarter are removed 
> dfend<-data.frame(ID= c("123",    "456",  "123", "789",   "456",  "789"),
+                   Drug= c("A",    "B",    "C",    "A",    "A",    "B"),
+                   Administered= c("2017 Q1",  "2018 Q1",  "2017 Q3",  "2017 Q1",  "2018 Q3",  "2018 Q1"))
> 
> print(dfend)
   ID Drug Administered
1 123    A      2017 Q1
2 456    B      2018 Q1
3 123    C      2017 Q3
4 789    A      2017 Q1
5 456    A      2018 Q3
6 789    B      2018 Q1
```

So as you can see when I used duplicate function it removed all duplicate ID's while I wanted to only remove duplicates within the same quarter of the year.
I have supplied my desired out put in the 'dfend' dataframe where cases 5, 8, and 9 have been removed as they were duplicate ID's within the same quarter of the year.
This data is a sample I created based off my original dataset which has >1500 enteries. I would like to be able to apply a function to achieve such results in a large dataset. I hope this edit better explains what I am looking for. Apologies for the previous post, slowly learning.

Thank you!

Comment: Images are a really bad way of posting data (or code). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the code you've tried and with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: You can edit your question to respond to the comments.

Comment: Hi Slanman. Please show your code, at least a snippet. To me, as a reader, code is the first thing i look for. Thanks.

Comment: @RonakShah The expected output is the dfend dataset in this edit.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I have posted the code to generate the sample dataframe and also supplied the dput(df) results in this edit.

Comment: @Loveandpeace-JoeCodeswell I have posted my code, I hope this is what you would like to see so you can help out. Thanks.

Comment: Looks good to me, Slanman. It makes it easier to quickly asses the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `duplicated` on selected columns.

```
Df[!duplicated(Df[c(1,3)]),]

#   ID Drug Administered
#1 123    A      2017 Q1
#2 456    B      2018 Q1
#3 123    C      2017 Q3
#4 789    A      2017 Q1
#6 456    A      2018 Q3
#7 789    B      2018 Q1
```

---

Using `dplyr`, we can `group_by` `ID` and `Administered` to select 1st row in each group.

We can do this with `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
Df %>% group_by(ID, Administered) %>%  slice(1L)
```

Or with `filter`

```
Df %>% group_by(ID, Administered) %>%  filter(row_number() == 1)
```

---

In `data.table` we can use `unique` and specify on which columns we want to check uniqueness.

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(Df), by = c('ID', 'Administered'))
```

Comment: WOW thank you! Those are alot of ways to get what I need. Thank you soo much! This is amazing!
However someone posted a previous solution to my question (which I think they took down) which was to use :
```
Df %>% distinct(ID, Administered, .keep_all = TRUE)
```
3 further questions:
1. Is it okay to use the "distinct" function that way too?
2. What is your preferred method out of all these?
3. In all these methods is acceptable and accurate to use all 3 variables i.e (ID, Drug, Administered) to identify unique cases?

I would appreciate it if you could also answer these. Thank you!

Comment: 1. Yes, you can use `distinct` that way. 2. My preferred way is 1st one using `duplicated` since it is base R and does not use any packages. 3. I guess that is accurate.